# PHP Combine two strings

Tags: php

Is there a way in php to make two strings combine to one? I want to combine strings with the same size together?

```
$string1 = "apple"
$string2 = "block"
//FUNCTION STUFF HERE
$output = "abplpolcek";
```

Comment: In C# we'd call it 'Zipping' two strings together, since they act like a zipper (1 side is put in, then the other; rinse, lather, repeat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$output='';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string1);$i++)
{
    $output.=$string1[$i];
    $output.=$string2[$i];
}

echo $output;
```

Or you can write a simple function like this:

```
function funnyConcatStrings($str1, $str2)
{
    $output='';
    $leng=strlen($str1);
    if(strlen($str1)==strlen($str2))
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$leng;$i++)
        {
            $output.=$str1[$i];
            $output.=$str2[$i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output='Strings were not equal.\n';
    }
    return $output;
}

// Use it like this:

$mashedString=funnyConcatStrings($string1, $string2);

// or

echo funnyConcatStrings($string1, $string2);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `strlen()` in the loop like that- it should be outside the loop as as it's not executed each iteration.

Comment: @VettelS I edited it again to make a nice function that replaces the initial answer.

Comment: I edited and put the `strlen($str1)` in the for loop, no need for that extra line. Also, why did you do `$output='';`? In a function that has no global variables it should have that value already.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandosn there is no need to check the length with each iteration - better to check it once and keep using that value, what if there were a billion iterations? That's a lot of wasted CPU cycles. As for the `$output='';` it is so that you can use the `.=` without throwing warnings.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str_length = 5;
$output = '';

for($i = 0; $i < $str_length; $i++)
{
    $output .= $string1[$i] . $string2[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use for instance $string1[0] ( letter 'a' ) to access the first letter and make a for loop

Comment: @Ionut Flavius Pogacian : Dode, you do not have to post code for such an easy task, we are here to provide answers based on the question, when learning you make baby steps, it was clear he didn`t know how to get characters from string

Comment: But you agree that this is high-school algorithmics and I assume that every person has basic programming knowledge and should use his brain...

Comment: yes, basics, but clearly, he does not know how to do it; he needs code, not explanations; ok, changing to +1

Answer (score 1):

Really easy;

```
$a = 'abcdef';
$b = 'ghijkl';

$l = strlen($a);

$s='';

for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++)$s .= $a[$i] + $b[$i];

echo $s;
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) Check if the string have the same lengts with [strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

2.) Then you can iterate through the string and access them as an array

```
$string = 'test123';
echo $string[0] -> 't'
```

Then you can combine the string and safe them in a new variable.

Comment: Then you should read the question. "I want to combine equal sized strings together?". He will combine equal sized string. This don't mean clearly that the string have the same length. So you should check it first.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for strings that are different lenght as well

```
$string1 = "apple";
$string2 = "block";

$arr1 = str_split($string1);
$arr2 = str_split($string2);

if(count($arr1) > 0)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $key => $value)
    {
        $_tmp[] = $value;
        if(isset($arr2[$key]))
        {
            $_tmp[] = $arr2[$key];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $key = 0;
}

if($key + 1 < count($arr2))
{
    for($i = $key + 1; $i < count($arr2); $i++)
    {
        $_tmp[] = $arr2[$key];
    }
}

echo implode("", $_tmp);
```

Comment: string is already an array of chars... `$x = 'string'; echo $x[2]; # r`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_shuffle("apple" . "block");
```

result: aekbplopcl

Comment: You need to provide an explenation as well, even if it is (quite) trivial.